# How to run a PHP file from ubuntu?

Tags: php

How to run a php file from ubuntu platform in the localhost? 
I have also installed LAMP in my system.
When I try to run the php file, in the browser, it says "The requested URL is not found-404 ERROR found". 
I do not know how to proceed with this.
My php files are in the directory as shown here "/usr/var/html/a.php".

Comment: "I have also installed LAMP in my system" — How?

Comment: "When I try to run the php file, in the browser" — How are you trying to do that? What are you typing? Where?

Comment: Just go to var/www/html/file.php it will be executable from localhost/file.php

Comment: "The requested URL is not found-404 ERROR found" — Look at the server logs. Do either the access log or the error log tell you the file path that the server tried to resolve that URL to?

Comment: People cant google.

Comment: What URL are you using to access the file

Comment: Just go to http://localhost/a.php and if you successfully installed LAMP (and started all services) it should work fine

Comment: In the address bar, I typed "http://localhost/var/www/html/a.php"

Comment: `/var/www/html/` is mapped to `http://localhost/` and/or in case of virtual hosts there are e.g. domain names like `http://www.mydomain.lan/` - whatever you have configured, or an external IP address.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are two options.

1. Access the php file through a local webserver(ie thru a local website). The web-server will deal with the requested php file. It will use either,

   - Inbuilt PHP module to interpret the php file, or
   - PHP through CGI (eg.CGI, FastCGI)


     If your apache(check if apache is running using `service apache2 status`!!) is set to the default configuration, this could be as simple as

     ```
     http://localhost/path/to/your.php
     ```

     Remember by default, the base directory for apache is `/var/www/html/`, so you need not include this in the url.
2. Use the php binary directly from a terminal.

   ```
      php /path/to/your/file.php
   ```

Comment: No I expect the php script to perform some calculations. Not just access it. I want to get the output in the browser.

Comment: I got it. Thank you.

Comment: @ShilpaJanarthanan : If the answer is helpful, you may accept it.

Answer (score 8):

After installation of Lamp system in Ubuntu. Please follow the below two steps to run your php file.

- Place your php file (.php) in /var/www/html/ (default path)
- Please run url as localhost/withfilename.php

Example : I have placed welcome.php file in the  `/var/www/html/welcome.php`
then url will be http://localhost/welcome.php